# SQL Select help needed

Tags: sql, facebook-fql

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge in this but I am trying to get the RSSBus Excel Add-In for Facebook which uses SQL to communicate with Facebook.

I am an admin on my personal account and also a company account.

I have set up as a developer in Facebook and have an appid, etc.

The RSSBus addin generates a SELECT statement `SELECT * FROM 'Events'` which will pull data into an Excel spreadsheet but it will only pull from my personal account.

I need to pull data from the company account.

I suspect I need to modify the `SELECT` to pull from the company account, but I have no idea how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your connection string to connect to the proper server.

Comment: How can I tell what server to connect to?